# C# ObjectMapper set list null if empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, treeview, objectmapper

I'm using this class as my permissions dto:

```
[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Permission))]
public class PermissionDto : PermissionDto2
{
    public PermissionDto2 Parent { get; set; }


}

[AutoMapFrom(typeof(Permission))]
public class PermissionDto2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Text => Name;
    public string Value => Name;

    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public List<PermissionDto2> Children { get; set; }

    private bool Disabled => false;
    private bool InternalDisabled => false;
}
```

And I'm using this function to get all my permissions:

```
    public List<PermissionDto> GetAllPermissions()
    {
        var permissions = ObjectMapper.Map<List<PermissionDto>>(_permissionManager.GetAllPermissions().Where(x => !x.Children.IsNullOrEmpty()));
        return permissions;
    }
```

When I execute this function, it returns this:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "parent": null,
      "name": "Pages",
      "displayName": "[Pages]",
      "text": "Pages",
      "value": "Pages",
      "checked": false,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Pages.Users",
          "displayName": "Users",
          "text": "Pages.Users",
          "value": "Pages.Users",
          "checked": false,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Pages.Users.Create",
              "displayName": "Users",
              "text": "Pages.Users.Create",
              "value": "Pages.Users.Create",
              "checked": false,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Pages.Users.Edit",
              "displayName": "Users",
              "text": "Pages.Users.Edit",
              "value": "Pages.Users.Edit",
              "checked": false,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Pages.Tenants",
          "displayName": "Tenants",
          "text": "Pages.Tenants",
          "value": "Pages.Tenants",
          "checked": false,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parent": {
        "name": "Pages",
        //...
```

The problem is that the plugin that I'm using to show these permissions as a treeview, [ngx-treeview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview), doesn't allow the children attribute to be empty, like it is in the permissions `Pages.Users.Create`, `Pages.Users.Edit` and `Pages.Tenants`; so, instead of the children being an empty list, I'd need it to be null. How could I do it?

Comment: What library is "AutoMapFrom" located in?

Comment: @KevinRaffay https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.AutoMapper/

Comment: I would start here: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Object-To-Object-Mapping.  It also points to AutoMapper, which is where you might want to check into config options to handle nulls.